How can I select rows from a table where the sum of rows in a joined table is greater than a number?
I have a order table and a payment table where multiple payments are joined to an order.
order



id
name




1
order 1


2
order 2



payment



id
order_id
amount




1
1
2000


2
1
3000


3
2
500


4
2
100



I want to SELECT all orders where the SUM of the payments are greater or less than a specific amount. How can I do that?
I think I need to JOIN the tables but I'm not sure how to SUM the amount in the payment table. I tried this:
SELECT * FROM "order"
JOIN payment ON payment.order_id = payment.id
WHERE (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM payment) > 2000

This does not result in any errors but I don't think the results are correct. I am expecting only "order 1" to be returned. Do I need to use GROUP BY or HAVING somehow?

You write you want to return the order name(s) only, but the query you have tried would return all columns from both orders and payment table. So what do you really want to return?

You were on the right track, but you need to 'correlate' the subquery to the row in the main query:
SELECT * 
FROM "order" o
      JOIN payment p 
      ON p.order_id = o.id
WHERE (SELECT SUM(amount) 
       FROM payment p1 
       where o.id=p1.order_id ) > 2000

There are other ways of doing the same.

I think o.order_id needs to be o.id but otherwise, I think this works. Thank you, your explanation has been helpful.

This will perform the worst of all the ways of doing it. You have a correlated subquery; it's executed for every row.

I think one should examine the execution plans to make a statement about performance. It may appear it would be executes row by row, this is only form a logical standpoint. In reality most compilers/optimisers can choose to execute this using one of the join methods, like nested-loops (row by row), hash join, merge join, etc. it depends on the indices, and the optimiser's knowledge of data distribution.

You need to use GROUP BY and HAVING clause
Just use the basic structure of GROUP BY and HAVING clause
SELECT a.ID, a.Name, sum(b.Amount) as TotAmt FROM public."order" a 
JOIN public.payment b ON a.ID=b.Order_ID
GROUP BY a.ID, a.Name HAVING sum(b.Amount) > 2000;

If you want to drop the column (sum(b.Amount) as TotAmt) from the result set just remove this column like it
SELECT a.ID, a.Name FROM public."order" a 
JOIN public.payment b ON a.ID=b.Order_ID
GROUP BY a.ID, a.Name HAVING sum(b.Amount) > 2000;


This works, thank you!

Use a subquery to find the id's of orders with more than 2000 payment amounts:
SELECT * FROM "order"
JOIN payment ON payment.order_id = payment.id
WHERE "order".id in (
  SELECT order_id
  FROM payment
  GROUP BY 1
  HAVING SUM(amount) > 2000
)

Handy note: You don't need to select an aggregated value to use it in a HAVING clause

How does GROUP BY 1 work?

@MichaelLynch it's short for "group by column number 1". In this case, equivalent to GROUP BY order_id
